# Why ";" is not used for i++ in a for loop. Doesn't everything have to end with ";"?

Tags: c

Why not use `;` after the `i++` in a for loop?

Consider,

```
for (int i= 0; i < 50; i++) {

}
```

In this case why people don't add `;` after `i++`?

Comment: They don't add it, because it is syntactically wrong. That's quite all what is  to say about that.

Comment: Because the grammar says so: `for ( {<expression>}? ; {<expression>}? ; {<expression>}? ) <statement>`.

Comment: Because it is one long sentence ending by }.

Comment: And what makes you think that a `;` needs to be added after the `i++`?

Comment: In C statements are terminated with a `;`. The control part of a `for` loop is no statement.

Comment: This post shows no research effort made prior to the post. Reading the syntax rules of the language is an important first step to reading/writing in any language. This is similar to asking why we write large numbers in English using commas instead of decimals like other languages (1000 -> {English} 1,000 or {Portuguese} 1.000). It is just the rules of their specific language.

Answer (score 12):

If you wrote `i++` as an independent statement you *would* need to put `;` after it.

```
void foo(int i)
{
    i++   // syntax error, missing ';'
}
```

But you don't need to put a semicolon after the third expression in a `for` loop header, because there is a close parenthesis to end it instead.   That's a rule about `for`, not a rule about `++`.  No matter what you put in a `for` loop header, you put a close parenthesis after the third expression, and not a semicolon.

```
for (listnode *p = list_head; *p; p = p->next) // correct
```

Answer (score 8):

Because it's in a for loop.
A for loop has the form:

```
for ( init_clause ; cond_expression ; iteration_expression ) loop_statement
```

`i++`  is an expression.
`i++;` is a statement.

Comment: So, that makes the `cond_expression ;` a statement? :) (You may need to re-word or clarify).

Comment: The for statement has special rules: The ; is used as a separator.

Comment: @Patrick: Sourav's point is that your answer needs to make that more clear - in the context of the loop control section, `;` is only used to separate the expressions.  Saying "i++ is an expression, i++; is a statement" doesn't apply in the control section.

Answer (score 3):

> In this case why people don't add ; behind of i++?

Because the language syntax doesn't allow it:

```
for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

In the control section of a `for` loop, the `;` acts as a *separator* between the three (optional) expressions, not as a statement terminator.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the for-loop is constructed which is the same in many other languages. The for-loop has 3 options which are seperated by `;`. The first options is the initial statement where you usually initialize the counter but you can add other things here and seperate these with `,` instead.
Here's an example:

```
(int i = 0, int k = 100; i < k; i++, k--)
```

And you don't have `;` after `i++` for the same reason you don't have it within methods parameters. For example you can't write `while(true;)`

Answer (score 2):

There is a distinction between an expression and a statement. For example, the following is considered an expression:

```
i++
```

while the following is considered an expression statement:

```
i++;
```

Since the standard specifies that the syntax of a `for` loop is:

```
for ( expression(opt) ; expression(opt) ; expression(opt) ) statement
```

it would be a syntax  error to add a semicolon `;` after the third expression because that would make it a statement, but what is expected is an optional expression.

Note: `opt` stands for optional.

Answer (score 0):

> Why “;” is not used for i++ in C language. Isn't everything to be end up “;”?

No, "everything" does not end with a semicolon.  Most *statements* and all *declarations* end with a semicolon, but `i++` is an *expression*.  That is, it expresses an operation that produces a value.  That it also has a side effect is not relevant to this analysis.  Other expressions include `i + 1`, `i > 0`, `i` alone, and even `i = 42`, among innumerable others.  None of these require a trailing semicolon in the general case, and all can be used as sub-expressions of more complex expressions.

C does have the concept of a "statement expression" wherein an expression can be used as a statement (for its side effects).  In that case, the statement is terminated by a semicolon, just like many other kinds of statements.  These are in fact very common indeed in C code, because assignments and function calls are expressions, and expression statements made from expressions of those types make up the bulk of most C codes.  But statements must not be construed as "everything".

> Why not use `;` after the `i++` in a for loop?

In the simplest possible terms, that's because the language requires that you not do so.  With respect to my preceding comments, it's because the third clause of a `for` statement's control block requires an expression, not a statement.